# Python list basics

Tags: python, list

I was going through the Apriori algorithm and was trying to solve it by using user defined function.
The code is available on Github -: https://gist.github.com/marcelcaraciolo/1423287

I am not able to get these two lines and how they are iterating in loops.

```
            L1 = list(freq_sets[i])[:k - 2]
            L2 = list(freq_sets[j])[:k - 2]
```

Actual function containing these line :

```
def aprioriGen(freq_sets, k):
    "Generate the joint transactions from candidate sets"
    retList = []
    lenLk = len(freq_sets)
    for i in range(lenLk):
        for j in range(i + 1, lenLk):
            L1 = list(freq_sets[i])[:k - 2]
            L2 = list(freq_sets[j])[:k - 2]
            L1.sort()
            L2.sort()
            if L1 == L2:
                retList.append(freq_sets[i] | freq_sets[j])
    return retList
```

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking. There is no loop here. The expression `list(...)[:k-2]` takes whatever is in `...` and turns it into a list, then returns that list without its `k-2` last elements. (The variable name `freq_sets` suggests that the input is a set, which you can't slice. Discarding the tail *before* sorting seems like a weird thing to do, and why are they not directly applying `sorted()` to the result? For what it's worth, `sorted(freq_sets[i])` would already return a list.)

Comment: Can you share input for freq_sets? something[:k - 2] is called slicing,in your case 'something' is a list so [:k-1] operator will slice the list from starting of the list to (k-1)th index. example if something = ['H', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', ' ', 'W', 'o', 'r', 'l', 'd'] and k is 10 then something[:k - 2] will be equals to ['H', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', ' ', 'W', 'o']